# Trying to extend flex datagrid to add an "add new row" row

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3

I am trying to extend the flex datagrid component so that I can have an "add new row" row like MS Access but I can't get it to work. I have tried a few different methods but I can't get anything to actually work.

By extend I really mean alter the Adobe code as some of the `private vars` I needed to do something else but I should be able to merge extend code with Adobe's.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the datagrid `editable` and then add a new object (or whatever you are using) with empty data to the datagrid's data provider.

[Here is an example](http://fivedigital.de/flex/editgrid/) I have created.

Comment: It is editable. I am using an `ArrayCollection`. I have tried that and added that code to `updateDisplayList` and invalidate it on change but it does nothing. If I remove the `invalidateDisplayList()` from my `addRows` setter, it will show but only when I click to edit another cell! Any more advice?

Comment: Thanks very much. I discovered that something was overwriting my `dataProvider` just after it added that row. Your example made me realise that my datagrid code was fine :)